# cant find prxdll.h and prx_attach/detach not working

Tags: c++

Alright so i was trying to modify a Visual Studio project (DLL Project). And i needed to
add prxdll.h and i needed to use prx_attach/detach.

```cpp
#include "dllmain.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "prxdll.h"
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(
    const HINSTANCE instance,
    const DWORD reason,
    const PVOID reserved)
{
    switch (reason) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
        DisableThreadLibraryCalls(instance);
        return prx_attach(instance);
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        prx_detach(reserved);
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

Im gettin an error that has a code with C1083 and it writes this:

"Cannot Open include file: 'prxdll.h': No such file or directory"

And also it says "identifier prx_attach() is undefined" (it says this for prx_detach() too).
Because of these errors i cant compile/build this.

Comment: Do you have that file installed anywhere?

Comment: no i cant find any documentation/file anywhere on internet.

Comment: Then talk to whoever maintained that project before you.

Comment: no one. This is a DLL Template. So i need to know what is this prx thing. Do you have a source for prxdll.h??

Comment: No.  Check the documentation for the template you found.  If you already performed a search though, it might be completely out of date.